# Inconsistent Template Matching

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the CreateEnvelope() method of the SOAP API to upload a document to DocuSign in the Draft status. When I do this and then request a Sender Token to start an Embedded Sending session, I'm immediately prompted to apply a matching template when the DocuSign interface appears.

If I don't start an Embedded Sending session, however, and the user instead logs into the DocuSign console and opens the Draft envelope, they are NOT automatically prompted to apply the matching template. They have to manually press the "Try automatic template matching on all documents" button, at which point the same template that would've been found automatically in the Embeddded Sending session is found. Is there a reason for this discrepancy?

```
bool retVal = true;

DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Envelope();

if (credentials == null)
{
    error = ErrorCode.NO_CREDENTIALS;
    errorMessage = Strings.GetString("STR_DS_NOCREDS");
    return false;
}
envelope.Documents = new DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Document[itemList.Count];
if (credentials != null)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (Document document in itemList)
    {
        DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Document doc = new DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Document();
        doc.ID = document.ID.ToString();
        doc.Name = document.Name;
        //get document bytes            
        doc.PDFBytes = document.data;
        envelope.Documents[index] = doc;
        index++;
    }

    Tab[] tabs = new DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.Tab[0];
    envelope.Tabs = tabs;
    envelope.Recipients = new Recipient[0];

    //send?
    envelope.AccountId = credentials.dsaccountid;    
    envelope.Subject = "Documents are ready for your signature";
    envelope.EmailBlurb = "Documents are awaiting your signature.";
    envelope.EnableWetSign = false;

    DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.EnvelopeStatus envStatus = new DocuSignService.DocuSignWS.EnvelopeStatus();

    using (ServiceWrapper client = new ServiceWrapper())
    {
        client.UserName = credentials.loginemail;
        client.Password = credentials.loginpassword;
        client.IntegratorKey = "xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";

        try
        {
            envStatus = client.CreateEnvelope(envelope);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorViewerWriter.Write(e);
            error = ErrorCode.UPLOADFAILED;
            errorMessage = e.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return retVal;
```

Comment: What does your envelope creation code look like?  And are you setting the CaptiveInfo (`clientUserId`) for your recipients to make them embedded?

Comment: I'm not setting CaptiveInfo, in fact in some scenarios I may be creating envelopes without recipients at all (they'll be specified during the embedded sending session). We are not implementing embedded signing at this time, just embedded sending.

Comment: Weird, I'm not experiencing that in my tests.  More info would be helpful though, as mentioned your envelope creation code might yield something if you want to post that.

Comment: @Ergin I created a simplified envelope creation function that shows the same issue as our integration code and edited it into my original post. Running this code and then getting a sender token for the envelope created prompts the user to apply a matched template during the embedded sending session. However, if I cancel out of the embedded send then login to devcenter outside of my application I am not prompted to apply the template when I open the exact same draft envelope (thought clicking the template match option finds the correct template).

Comment: I suppose the answer could be that the prompt is supposed to happen during the embedded send but now while opening a draft envelope, but I just wanted to be clear.